# Stacking R, G & B channels to an Image in Go lang

Tags: go, image-processing

I have the following three R, G and B channels I have convoluted from a "BGGR" colour filter array. The values aren't important, except to say I have three flattened arrays where convolution have been performed on (or will be):

R channel

```golang
[123 120 117 61.5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 123 93 63 34.75 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.75 7 6.5 123 66 9 8 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7.5 8 8 64.5 36 7.5 7 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.75 7 7.5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6.5 7 7.5 7 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.75 7 6.5 7 8 9 8 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7.5 8 8 6.5 7 7.5 7 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.75 7 7.5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6.5 7 7.5 7 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.75 7 6.5 7 8 9 8 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7.5 8 8 6.5 7 7.5 7 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.75 7 7.5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6.5 7 7.5 7 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.5 6.75 7 6.5 7 8 9 8 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7.5 8 8 7 7.5 9 8.5 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7.25 8 8]
```

G channel

```golang
[1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

B channel

```golang
[1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

I now have the three channels, all of length 256 from an original 16x16 matrix. The first 16 values in the array of length 256 represent the first row, column 1 - 16.

Now, I thought that it would now be super simple to stack the three arrays:

```golang
for i := 0; i < b.Height; i++ {
    for j := 0; j < b.Width; j++ {
        b.Image.Set(i, j, color.RGBA{
            R: uint8(red[i*b.Height+j]),
            G: uint8(green[i*b.Height+j]),
            B: uint8(blue[i*b.Height+j]),
            A: 255,
        })
    }
}
```

I then have an image, `b.Image`, which I save to JPEG:

```golang
var buff bytes.Buffer

// Encode the image as a JPEG:
err := jpeg.Encode(&buff, b.Image, &jpeg.Options{Quality: 100})

if err != nil {
    return buff, err
}

// Write to file.
f, err := os.Create("convolution_test.png")

if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}

defer f.Close()

fw := bufio.NewWriter(f)

fw.Write(buf.Bytes())
```

However, when I got to open the image - something has gone wrong and I am unable to seeing errors like "An error occurred while loading the image"

Can anyone point me to where I have gone wrong here?

Comment: Note: I thought it would be related to encoding an alpha channel to JPEG, but it seems to not matter even if I encode with the "image/png" package ...

Comment: You saved a JPG file as PNG?

Comment: Hi Burak, unfortunately, not. That's just a typo in the question, if I encode as either png or jpeg, and save to their respective file types, I still get the error showing up ...

Comment: Another thing: you never closed or flushed fw. You don't really need a buffered writer here. You can directly write to `f`

Comment: Hi Burak, in reality I'm sending the buffer bytes across the wire to be stored on an s3 bucket ... I believe I need to buffer writer to stay.

Comment: Ahhh well done, looks like the flushing has worked! Thank you!

Comment: You don't  need the buffered writer. You have everything in a buffer already.

Comment: Please explain ...

Comment: You encoded the image into a `bytes.Buffer`. You can simply write that buffer directly. If you're sending this over a network connection, you probably have a `io.Writer` from that connection, so you can simply do `io.Copy`